# Preencher input dinamicamente com angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Amigos, ajudem-me a fazer um script no qual eu possa acrescentar palavras a um input, conforme seja clicado um botão. As palavras devem ficar lado a lado e separadas por virgular:

> palavra1, palavra2, palavra3

Isso me dar um input, conforme adiciono, com o valor preenchido, mas não quero gerar vários inputs e sim **somente um com palavras, como no exemplo acima**:

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="palavra">

<div ng-click="addpalavra(palavra);">+</div>

<div ng-show="palavra">                                                             

<span ng-repeat="palavra in project.palavras track by $index" ng-show="$index>0 || $parent.$index>0">{{ palavra }} 

<input type="hidden" name="palavra[]" value ="{{palavra}}" ng-model="palavra" >
```

```
<script>
  $scope.palavra = function(palavra) {
      project.palavras.push(palavra);
        };
</script>
```

> ESTE É UM EXEMPLO, DO CÓDIGO ACIMA: http://jsfiddle.net/aohegdnr/

Comment: Ofereço reputação para a sua próximo pergunta.

Comment: Não coloque o atributo `ng-repeat` no `span`. Dessa forma não existirá um `span` para cada elemento na lista de palavras.

Comment: até aí tudo bem, mas como adiciono ao input essa sequencia de valores?

Comment: Você quer um `input` para todas as palavras? Ou um `input` para uma palavra de cada vez?

Comment: Um input com várias palavras separadas por vírgulas, conforme vou adicionando, através de outro input.

Comment: Consegue replicar esse problema num JSFiddle ou JSBin? Quem sabe aí podemos dar uma ajuda.

Comment: @mutlei, está aqui > http://jsfiddle.net/aohegdnr/

Comment: isso aqui soluciona o problema? http://jsfiddle.net/tn224w2d/

Comment: Muito interessante, consegue por dentro de um input e separado por vírgula? abraço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito o que você deseja. Seria apenas exibir as tags, separadas por `', '`, dentro de um input?

Ficaria assim:

```
<input class="form-control" value="{{ project.tags.join(', ') }}">
```

[Exemplo.](http://jsfiddle.net/aohegdnr/1/)

Comment: Sempre sendo mestre em Angular, iuristona!